# How the encode method return an non-hex code point in Python?

Tags: python, encoding, decoding, hexdump

There are some special chinese words like '觱' '踨', when I check its code point of **gb18030** as follow.

> >>>`u'觱'.encode('gb18030')`
>   `'\xd3v'`

I have been confused about the code point **'\xd3v'**. It's not a correct hex-digits.
Who can explain it clearly?

Actually, I have a task that converting code points of **gb18030**,like 'CDF2' 'F4A5' etc..., into
its corresponding unicode encoding.

> >>>`'CDF2'.decode('hex').decode('gb18030')`
>   `u'\u4e07'`

**But**,

> >>>`'d3v'.decode('hex').decode('gb18030')`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/hex_codec.py", line 42, in hex_decode
        output = binascii.a2b_hex(input)
    TypeError: Odd-length string
```

So, I don't understand why the encode method return an non-hex code point.
For example, what's the meaning 'v' of '\xd3v'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'\xd3v' == '\xd3\x76'`. Python prints ASCII printables (including `\n`, `\t`, ...) as a letter instead of hexadecimal form.

```
>>> '\xd3v' == '\xd3\x76'
True
```

If you want to get hexadeicmal format, use `encode('hex')` (as you did for decode)

```
>>> u'觱'.encode('gb18030').encode('hex')
'd376'
```

or using `binascii.hexlify`:

```
>>> binascii.hexlify(u'觱'.encode('gb18030'))
'd376'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a "v" - the character encoded in the "gb18030" encoding is represented by two bytes, one being "\xd3" - dec 211 - and the other one being dec-118.  The default behavior for Python 2.x when showing a byte-string representation is to display bytes in the ASCII rabge of 32-127 as their ASCII encoding, and characters outside this range as 2 digit heexadecimal escapes.

```
Thus:
>>> a = u'觱'.encode('gb18030')
>>> ord(a[0])
211
>>> ord(a[1])
118
```

Now, if you are editing this in a gb18030 terminal, just seeing the actual STR representation, instead of repr, would show you the original chinese character.

```
>>> print a
```